# Computing a recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can we simplify a sequence given by $$a(n+1) = (a(n) +77)^{1/4}$$ where, $$a(1) = 77^{1/4}$$ What can we say about its integer part?

Comment: 1. Finding a simple formula for every a(n) is (useless and) not doable. 2. Finding the limit of a(n) when n goes to infinity is (useful and) a classical task. 3. Where is your input on this?

Comment: It's easy enough to show that if $x<3$, then $(x+77)^{1/4}<3$. Does that help?

Comment: @Did Essentially, what is required is the integer part for a(1000) .

Comment: Then your question is still quite misleading. The integer part of a(1000) is obviously $$2$$

Comment: No no , that's what was needed. It didn't strike me instantly. Now I get it. I thought simplifying the expression might give us some sort of a special sequence that has some property that I don't know off